Howto enable font embedding with tikzfadingfrompicture? (Use case: Text color gradient)
I want to display a (very big) partially transparent emoji in the background of a document with a color gradient on the emoji).
So far, the only successful way for doing so seemed the following tikz solution using tikzfadingfrompicture
For the easier reproduction/testing, I've changed the emoji to the Letter T in the following MWE.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\emojifont[Scale=1.0]{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}
 

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put (1.5in,-4.5in){
        \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=backgroundemojibus]
        \node [text=transparent!40] (textnodebus)
        {
            \emojifont\fontsize{360}{360}\selectfont T
        };
        \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[path fading=backgroundemojibus,fit fading=false, opacity=0.4, left color=green,right color=blue](textnodebus.south west) rectangle (textnodebus.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}

Whether i compile this with lualatex or xelatex is irrelevant.
The Emoji font is embedded in neither case:

$ pdffonts test-fontembedding.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID

RMPGEQ+DejaVuSans                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     39  0

But the LuaLaTeX output shows that the necessity of the font is known:
$ lualatex test-fontembedding.tex
...
(./test-fontembedding.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)){/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.m
ap} [1] (./test-fontembedding.aux))
 933 words of node memory still in use:
   19 hlist, 1 vlist, 9 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 53 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 53 attribute_list, 2 write, 16 pdf_literal, 16 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:135,3:71,4:10,5:106,6:2,7:1800,9:64,10:7,11:144
</usr/share/fonts/truetype/LinBiolinum_R.otf></usr/share/fonts/truetype/EmojiOneColor-SVGinOT.ttf>
Output written on test-fontembedding.pdf (1 page, 16519 bytes).
Transcript written on test-fontembedding.log.

Even changing the tikzfadingfrompicture \node doesn't fix this
\node [font=\emojifont,text=transparent!40] (textnodebus)
{
    \fontsize{360}{360}\selectfont T
};

The difference without the (not) embedded font shows on a System, where the font is not installed:

vs

Another note for comparison: Changing the code to use no color gradient, like this fixes the problem, the font is embedded afterwards and will the Glyph in the background will be shown on any system.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [text=transparent!40]
{
   \emojifont\color{red}\fontsize{360}{360}\selectfont T
};
\end{tikzpicture}


$ pdffonts test-fontembedding.tex
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID

XQLTJA+DejaVuSerif                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     32  0
RMPGEQ+DejaVuSans                    CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     33  0

Another Note:
Running

$ gs -P- -dSAFER -q -P- -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=test-fontembedding.full.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dEmbedAllFonts=true test-fontembedding.pdf

will fix the problem afterwards too (for the output file of gs), so the skipped embedding of the font is the whole problem.
So, naturally, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong or where I'm disabling the font embedding with the color gradient code. Are there any solutions to this problem?
//EDIT:

changed fonts to common fonts, Emoji to Letter T
added screenshots from my system and my phone (which doesn't have the fonts installed)


Welcome to TeX.SX!

Don't load fontenc if you're using fontspec. You don't want the T1 encoding if you're using unicode. Can you reproduce with a font everyone has?

@cfr I removed the fontenc line and changed the Font to "Noto Emoji" with the same results. (And the same goes for "Linux Libertine O" oder "Hack" (but in those cases, the font have no glyph for that Codepoint, so there is a warning and i get the default missing glyph of each font displayed, but no font embedded)

The thing is, you don't need that character to reproduce the problem. Just make an example with some regular letter or word in it. Otherwise, you get a fatal error (or I do) rather than reproducing the problem.

Does it matter if the font is embedded or not? It isn't actually used in the PDF, after all.

I've edited the question and the MWE to use two other fonts and the letter 'T' instead of an emoji. I've also added screenshots to demonstrate the Problem. And of course it matters wheter the font is embedded in the pdf as the font is used in the PDF, which is also shown by the screenshots.
